# Google My Business API: issue obtaining Reviews

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

What's been done so far:

- The Prerequisites and Basic Setup steps have been followed, and our
  account has been granted access to "Google My Business API". (The
  dashboard says "Activation status: Enabled")
- In the APIs section of
  google, a Service Account has been created under the Google Project
  with the role of Editor.
- In the My Business section of google i can
  see our 6 published/verified Locations.

When our website uses the Service Account to interrogate the "List all reviews" api method, the exception back is **"Google.GoogleApiException: 'Parameter validation failed for "parent"'"**

A bit more about our code: Its asp.net and using a "Google.Apis.MyBusiness.v4" nuget package generated from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1352#issuecomment-475167066. I have downloaded the JWT file from the google dashboard, and the credential and business service objects are constructed as follows:

```
var scopes = new List<string>()
  {
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
  };

  var stream = new FileStream("key.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
  credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

  var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
   ApplicationName = "Google Reviews",
  };
  var service = new MyBusinessService(initializer);
```

And the Reviews api call where the exception happens

```
  var reviewsListRequest = service.Accounts.Locations.Reviews.List("our location name here");
  var listReviewsResponse = reviewsListRequest.Execute();
```

So the question is what isn't set up correctly and causing that exception?

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
var reviewsListRequest = service.Accounts.Locations.Get("accounts/accountnumber")
```

^^ WILL WORK

```
var reviewsListRequest = service.Accounts.Locations.Get("accountnumber");
```

^^ WILL NOT WORK

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a lot more. Google's documentation for this is so difficult to find the right information from. Thanks for the info, friend!